# Cortar áudio com javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, html5-audio

Galera preciso cortar um áudio no client-side e enviar os bytes "cortados" para o NodeJS. É possível? Como posso implementar?

Comment: Porque não fazer isso no Node.js? (curiosidade, pois é bem mais fácil gerir ficheiros e garantir processamento no lado do servidor)

Comment: @Sergio queria que o usuário não precisasse enviar o arquivo completo (uma música) para o servidor. Queria deixar a cargo dele cortar o áudio e enviar o tamanho que bem entender. Mas o problema é que preciso fazer com JS, apenas JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createBuffer nesse link tem um exemplo onde se cria um buffer de áudio vazio e depois se preenche ele. Minha teoria seria abrir o arquivo percorrer os bytes e pegar um intervalo depois enviar ao node.js, mas não sei como implementar.

Answer (score 2):

Bem, consegui resolver meu problema e voltei aqui para compartilhar a solução para alguém que futuramente também precise. Até porque não encontrei nada parecido na net por mais incrível que pareça.

**VanillaJS**

```
window.onload = function (){
  'use strict';

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",'path/da/musica', true);
    xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        var blob    = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: "audio/mp3"});
        var newBlob = new Blob([blob.slice(/*Início em bytes*/, /*Fim em bytes*/)],    {type:"audio/mp3"});

        var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(){

            var dataURL = reader.result;
            var output = document.getElementById('audio');
            output.src = dataURL;
            output.autoplay = true;
       };

        reader.readAsDataURL(newBlob);

    }

    xhr.send(null);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<audio id="audio"></audio>
```

**Nota: não me utilizei da forma mais ortodoxa, mas é funcional**

Comment: acredito que terá problemas se o `MP3` tiver sido encodado com `VBR (Variable Bit Rate encoding)`, neste caso não é possível prever a posição inicial e final, afinal o `bitrate` não será constante, então você terá de exigir ou verificar que o `MP3` seja encondado usando `CBR (Constant Bit Rate encoding)`.